# Python - calling wrapper function after naming function it wraps

Tags: python, namespaces, wrapper

I honestly don't know if this is good, bad, neutral, whatever.

```
def foo():
    return "foo called"

def bar():
    return "BAR CALLED"

def wrap(func):
    def _(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            func.counter += 1
        except:
            func.counter = 0
        print "The count is %d" % func.counter
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return _

>>> foo = wrap(foo)
>>> bar = wrap(bar)
>>> foo()
'The count is 0'
'foo called'
>>> foo()
'The count is 1'
'foo called'
>>> bar()
'The count is 0'
'BAR CALLED'
```

So far, so good -- functions are just wrapped, no big deal. Here's the bit that I don't know whether to consider a feature or not.

```
>>> foo
<function _ at 0x100499ed8>
>>> _()
The count is 2
'foo called'
>>> bar
<function _ at 0x10049f320>
>>> _()
The count is 1
'BAR CALLED'
>>>
```

Perhaps I know too little of the behind-the-scenes here, but Python has two wrapper functions in memory named `_`, and a user can apparently 'switch' between them by just typing the name of the function it wraps.

Is this a feature, and if it is, what would its primary application be? Or if it is not, is this best left forgotten about, because it's just a Bad Idea to try and featurize this behavior? My journeyman guess is that this is only doable because there are not real closures in Python (which probably puts it under `We're all adults here` and I should not ever try to actually do this), but that's an uneducated guess.

Comment: As a side note, if you want to avoid the function being named `_`, use the [`wraps`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) decorator inside your decorator. Like [this](http://pastebin.com/38pWdaQq). Then the name (and docstring, module, and signature annotations) of the wrapped function will be the same as the original function.

Comment: Also, you might find something like [this](http://pastebin.com/hNwaiCjT) a little simpler and nicer (nicer because, e.g., you can look at the `count` attribute from outside of the function call without needing a `try`).

Comment: By the way, "there are not real closures in Python" is not true. The wrapped-up `foo` _is_ a closure, with the original unwrapped `foo` as a closure cell (you can even inspect it as `foo.func_closure[0]`). That's how it's able to mutate the `func` variable from the `wrap` frame (even after `wrap` has returned). Which is exactly what a closure is. What Python 2.x _can't_ do is rebind a name in the enclosing space, but then neither can many functional languages—and Python 3.x _can_ do that, with a `nonlocal` statement.

Comment: Perhaps I conflated closures with encapsulation (or perhaps I'm just incorrect again, again). In any event, thanks for the extra information.

Comment: I don't think it's true that Python doesn't have encapsulation, either. Of course a lot of Java and Ruby users _say_ that, but I think it's a lot of nonsense. See [here](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2014/01/python-doesnt-have-encapsulation.html) for more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a shortcut of the Python interpreter. The result of the last expression evaluated is assigned to `_` so that you can use it in subsequent operations.

Like:

```
>>> 5 + 7
12
>>> _ * 2
24
>>> _ + 3
27
```

Please note that this will work only in an *interactive* shell, not in a script, and only when `_` isn't already defined by you.

Comment: Oh ew, so I should not use `_` to name the inner function in a wrapper then, should I

Comment: There is no problem with that, the `_` trick only works in interactive  shell and only if it was not assigned before. I would use a more meaningful name, though.

Comment: @Stick: It doesn't matter. It's a local variable; it won't conflict. If you ever do anything with internationalization, though, `_` is often expected to be `gettext`.